# Define Table Header for Mardown Table of +---+---+ Markup Type

Tags: markdown, pandoc, tableheader

What markup should be used to turn the first row into a table header?

```
+-------+----------+-------------------------------------------------+
|  Bits |   Field  |                   Description                   |
|       |   Name   |                                                 |
+-------+----------+-------------------------------------------------+
| 31:28 |  FORMAT  | Indicates size of data type in buffer in bytes  |
|       |          | Indicates size of data type in buffer in bytes  |
|       |          | Indicates size of data type in buffer in bytes  |
|       |          | Indicates size of data type in buffer in bytes  |
+-------+----------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears to be Pandoc's [grid_tables](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-grid_tables). The header should be separated from the body by `=`, like this:

```
+-------+----------+-------------------------------------------------+
|  Bits |   Field  |                   Description                   |
|       |   Name   |                                                 |
+=======+==========+=================================================+
| 31:28 |  FORMAT  | Indicates size of data type in buffer in bytes  |
|       |          | Indicates size of data type in buffer in bytes  |
|       |          | Indicates size of data type in buffer in bytes  |
|       |          | Indicates size of data type in buffer in bytes  |
+-------+----------+-------------------------------------------------+
```